# Running any web server event loop on a secondary thread

Tags: python, multithreading, embeddedwebserver

We have a rich backend application that handles messaging/queuing, database queries, and computer vision.  An additional feature we need is tcp communication - preferably via http. The point is: this is not *primarily* a web application.   We would expect to have a set of http channels set up for different purposes.  Yes - we understand about messaging including topics and publish-subscribe: but direct tcp based request/response also has its place.

I have looked at and tried out a half dozen python http web servers. They either implicitly or explicitly describe a requirement to run the `event loop` on the *main* thread.  This is for us a cart before the horse: the `main` thread is already occupied with other tasks including coordination of the other activities.

To illustrate the intended structure I will lift code from my `aiohttp`-specific question [How to run an aiohttp web application in a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959058/how-to-run-an-aiohttp-web-application-in-a-secondary-thread).  In that question  I tried running in another standalone script but on a subservient thread:

```
def runWebapp():
  from aiohttp import web

  async def handle(request):
      name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
      text = "Hello, " + name
      return web.Response(text=text)

  app = web.Application()
  app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                  web.get('/{name}', handle)])
  web.run_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from threading import Thread
  t = Thread(target=runWebapp)
  t.start()
  print('thread started let''s nap..')
  import time
  time.sleep(50)
```

This gives error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

This error turns out to mean "hey you're not running this on the `main` thread".

We can logically replace `aiohttp` with other web servers here. Are there any for which this approach of asking the web server's event handling loop to run on a secondary thread will work? So far I have also tried `cherrypy`, `tornado`, and `flask`.

Note that one prominent webserver that  I have not tried is `django`.  But that one seems to require an extensive restructuring of the application around the directory structures expected (/required?) for `django`.  We would not want to do that given the application has a set of other purposes that supersede this sideshow of having http servers.

An approach that I have *looked* at is `asyncio`. I have not understood whether it can support running event loops on a side thread or not: if so then it would be an answer to this question.

In any case are there any web servers that explicitly support having their event loops off of the main thread?

Comment: Also, check this out about `asyncio`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059732/send-asyncio-tasks-to-loop-running-in-other-thread and also https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and set an event loop while on the secondary thread:

```py
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
```

`cherrypy` and `flask` already work without this; `tornado` works with this.

On `aiohttp`, you get another error from it calling `loop.add_signal_handler()`:

> ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread

You need to skip that because [only the main thread of the main interpreter is allowed to set a new signal handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads), which means web servers running on a secondary thread cannot directly handle signals to do graceful exit.

## Example: aiohttp

1. Set the event loop before calling `run_app()`.
   `aiohttp` 3.8+ already [uses a new event loop in `run_app()`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/5572), so you can skip this.
2. Pass `handle_signals=False` when calling `run_app()` to not add signal handlers.

```py
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())  # aiohttp<3.8
web.run_app(app, handle_signals=False)
```

## Example: tornado

Set the event loop before calling `app.listen()`.

```py
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: so by `web.run_app(app, handle_signals=False)` does this have any effect /require some additional involvement by the main thread?

Comment: No, just that `aiohttp` can't do graceful exit.

Comment: ah ok. I think this might have really helped me 22 months ago

Answer (score 1):

Any Python program is run on a single thread which is the `main`. And when you create a `Thread` it does not mean that your program already uses two threads.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use different event loops for every `Thread` but possible to do that using `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`.
It allows creating its own event loop for every single `Process`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from aiohttp import web


def runWebapp(port):
    async def handle(request):
        name = request.match_info.get("name", "Anonymous")
        text = "Hello, " + name
        return web.Response(text=text)

    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        web.get("/", handle),
        web.get("/{name}", handle)
    ])
    web.run_app(app, port=port)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=runWebapp, args=(8080,))
    p2 = Process(target=runWebapp, args=(8081,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: That's a useful structure.